# Orthonormalized basis of linearly dependent system

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, orthonormal

Given the following vectors:

[image]

How is the orthonormalised basis of the span{v1, v2, v3} calculated?
Given it is linearly dependent do you just need to work out the orthonormalised basis of the span {v1,v2}?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since $\text{Span} \{v_1, v_2, v_3 \} = \text{Span}\{v_1, v_2 \}$, you can orthonormalize the set $\{v_1, v_2 \}$ using the Gram-Schmidt process with normalization.